# Twilio: Send SMS from Twilio and log it through the Messaging Request URL?

Tags: post, sms, twilio

I know how to capture information about SMS messages going to my Twilio number by making use of their Message Request URL facility.

However, this facility only seems to capture info about SMS messages going ***to*** my Twilio phone number.

Is there some way to send an SMS message ***from*** my Twilio phone number and also have it logged in the same way via the same Message Request URL?

For example, I know I can do the following to send an SMS from my Twilio phone number ...

```
#!/bin/sh

sid='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
token='YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY'
from='12125551212'  # assume this is my Twilio phone number
to='9999999999'
text='Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their party.'

/usr/bin/curl \
  -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/${sid}/Messages \                                         
  -u "${sid}:${token}" -d "From=${from}" -d "To=${to}" \                               
  --data-urlencode "Body=${text}"
```

However, this message does not get logged via my Message Request URL.

I know that I can put a wrapper around this and make an additional direct call to curl which will also post to my Message Request URL using similar parameters to what Twilio uses in the SMS-from-someone-else-to-Twilio case.

However, is there some way to get Twilio to automatically notify my Message Request URL of these Twilio-to-someone-else SMS's? ... perhaps via extra parameters to the POST request?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

You could specify the [StatusCallback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-sms#post-parameters-optional) parameter in your cURL request.  This will have Twilio make a request to that URL once your message is processed.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. I guess it isn't possible to _permanently_ register a Status Callback with Twilio, in a similar manner to the Message Request URL ... correct? That would be ideal for me, if it were possible. But I guess I could live with the request-specific StatusCallback.

Comment: Ya, it does not look like you can do that.